# Main Activity Listener in a Custom View?

Tags: android, interface, listener, android-custom-view, listeners

Hey I am trying to get real time data change in the main activity in my custom view. I want to implement a listener for the view, such that whenever anything changes in my Main Activity, my View gets to know about that and act accordingly.

Following is in my Main Activity.

```
public void setChangeListener(OnChangeListener onChangeListener){
    this.onChangeListener = onChangeListener;
}

public interface OnChangeListener{
    void currentRadius(int r);
    void currentSpeed(int s);
}
```

I have initialized the same in View as,

```
public CustomView extends View{

//CONSTRUCTORS

//EVERYTHING ELSE

    //These are inside the init(Context context) method.
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        mainActivity.setOnChangeListener(new MainActivity.OnChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void currentR(int r) {
                Log.d("R", ""+r);
            }

            @Override
            public void currentS(int s) {
                Log.d("S", ""+s);
            }
        });

}
```

But this is giving me NullPointerException at

```
onChangeListener.currentR(//INTEGER VALUE);
onChangeListener.currentS(//INTEGER VALUE);
```

which are inside a `onProgressChanged` Listener.

What I want to ask is that is it even possible to send data using Listeners from Activity to View? If yes, then any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what is view? explain

Comment: From where `onProgressChanged` call ?  Form `Aysnc Task`?

Comment: @MayurRaval No, it is a seekbar progress change listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MainActivity`

```
CustomView mCustomeView =  new CustomView(this); // or Resource id
```

Create methods in `CustomView`

```
        public void currentR(int r) {
            Log.d("R", ""+r);
        }

        public void currentS(int s) {
            Log.d("S", ""+s);
        }
```

Then call that methods from `MainActivity`

```
mCustomeView.currentR(integervalue);
mCustomeView.currentS(integervalue);
```

**NOTE:Be sure that if you change UI from that methods. It will be in Main UI Thread . other wise it will throw error**

Hope This help

Comment: Thanks, I was able to achieve what I was looking for. (Y)

Answer (score 0):

> MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();

Do not instantiate an Activity. Pass `MainActivity` context to the view and use that to do operations. 
sample context

```
Context context = MainActivty.this;
```

Comment: I tried that, I am anyway passing the context in the Constructor of the view, but I cannot use that to call `setOnChangeListener` and create a Listener of the same,